# how send post request and open url in Ruby Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

i am sending a post request,
and need to get result like with html form, 
where we going to some url after doing request

```
<form action="url" method="post">
```

i tried this:

```
return response.body()
```

and i get only body of html page, 
but i need to redirect to this page.
what right way to go to needed URL?

here my code for post request:

```
    post '/send' do
            uri = URI.parse("https://wl.walletone.com/checkout/checkout/Index")
            response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {
                "WMI_MERCHANT_ID" => "xxx",
                "WMI_PAYMENT_AMOUNT" => "10.00",
                "WMI_CURRENCY_ID" => "643"
            })
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to directly pass along a POST request and redirect to it, you can do

```
post '/send' do
  redirect <your_url>, 307
end
```

`307` is the HTTP status code to not modify the request method.

Handle a redirect response like this:

```
post '/send' do
  # post form
  redirect response['location'], 302
end
```

Comment: No, i need modify recieved post request to "/send", add some fields, and send it to walletone.com

Comment: Does the response not have a redirect location?

Comment: what for this location? i have `uri`

Comment: No, the response you get from the `post_form` method. What status code do you get? 200 OK or 302 redirect etc...

Comment: wow, now `response.body` is: `<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/checkout/checkout/Index?i=334742142681&amp;m=191554294939">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>`

Comment: with `redirect "https://wl.walletone.com/checkout/checkout/Index", 307`? no it did not work, because `Object moved to <a......`

Comment: Oops, sorry. Check now.

Comment: woohoo! it works! with litlle change: `redirect "https://wl.walletone.com"+response['location'], 302`. Thank you very much rohit89!